# jQuery Mobile pageload code with params not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#home").on("pageload", function() {
    console.log("test2");
    var url = window.location.search;
    var split = url.split('=');
    var vendorID = split[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vendorpull.php",
        data: 'id=' + vendorID,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            document.getElementById('vendor-data').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
});
```

This code does not seem to be firing unless the page is physically refreshed. I've tried pageshow, pagebeforeshow and others and it doesn't change. The test console.log does not even fire. This event should be trigged as soon as vendor.html?id=1 is loaded, that is the page that is navigated to containing the above AJAX code. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: Exactly if you want to insert some data in DOM the why you are usng pageload directly call this url onclick and whatever data you will get insert it to the you dom there is no requirement of pageload if youwant to achive this sort of result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#home").ready(function() { //You can also use $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("test2");
    var url = window.location.search;
    var split = url.split('=');
    var vendorID = split[1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vendorpull.php",
        data: 'id=' + vendorID,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            document.getElementById('vendor-data').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code for jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 will reload data for every page visit:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) { 
    var pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
    /* JQM NAVIGATE #2 */
    if (typeof ui.toPage == "object") {
        /* manipulate page navigating to */
        switch (pageId) {
            case "home":
                var url = window.location.search;
                var split = url.split('=');
                var vendorID = split[1];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "vendorpull.php",
                    data: 'id=' + vendorID,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading("show");
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#vendor-data").html(data);
                        $("#home .ui-content").trigger("updatelayout");
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading("hide");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading("hide");
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:;
        }
    }
});
```